# responsive site in joomla with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm going to learn bootstrap for responsive site design and downloaded it and set the followings in joomla 2.5:

1. unzipped the bootstrap package and renamed it with assets
2. copied the assests folder inside the template (beez5)
3. defined the following in `<head>` section of index.php:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

To test it's css I defined `background-color: red !important;` to container-fluid in bootstrap.css and added a class `container-fluid` in main div in index.php but I think the css is not working. I mean bootstrap css is not loading.

**Question:** How to implement bootstrap css for responsive site in joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is here: [Joomla Communite Magazine, Issue 2012 August](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-aug-2012/item/818-using-the-twitter-bootstrap-framework-to-build-a-responsive-joomla-template-from-scratch).

*You have three options for creating a new template*

1. start from scratch with creating a folder and all the necessary
   files (**the article is focused in this point**)
2. install a starter theme and modify it
3. copy an existing template and modify it

If you are interested in [Out-of-box](https://github.com/gsuez/joomla-master-bootstrap) solution.

---

PS: to load css files, something like this should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

`$this->baseurl` contains the location within your domain that Joomla is installed at.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar I would suggest you to download the example from git and see how it works. After you understand, just replicate to your case.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar but with a 404? If so, you have your path incorrect with file system. do a var_dump to ensure the correct path. (pay attention to Case sensitive)